# NSUTF8StringEncoding problem in nsdata to nsstring convertion

Tags: html, nsstring, nsdata, nsutf8encoding

I have a Mac Os App that retrieve the html code of a web page and put it in a NSString. The code is:

```
NSString*linkURL=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"https://www.example.com"];
NSURL *targetURL=[NSURL URLWithString:linkURL];
NSData *htmlData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:targetURL];
NSString *dataString=[[NSString alloc]initWithData:htmlData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
```

This app runs on Mac OsX 10.8 and works fine.
After system update to Mac OsX 10.12 I have a problem with the `NSUTF8StringEncoding`.
The `NSString *dataString` contains only a part of the html code and not the entire html code.

I verified that `htmlData` contains the right code because I write `htmlData` to a txt file and it contains all the html code that I retrieved.
But when I initialize the `NSString` with the `htmlData` using NSUTF8StringEncoding the string contains only the first part of the html code.

I tried also:

```
NSString *dataString=[[NSString alloc]initWithUTF8String:[tutorialsHtmlData bytes]];
```

with the same result.

Also the code:

```
NSString *dataString=[NSString stringWithContentsOfURL:targetURL encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:nil];
```

gave me the same result.

The html code of the web page is UTF-8 coded, this is its meta:

```
<head> 
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
```

Anyone can help me? Thanks